# Работа с данными консоли

Tags: shell, debian, bash

Здравствуйте! Имеется задача получить данные из консоли и в зависимости от их содержания сделать те или иные действия.
Имеется скрипт, который запускает приложения в скрине. Таких приложении более 20. Обходить каждый в ручную не выгодно. Поэтому хочу сделать скрипт, который будет сам обходить приложения.т.е. идти по всем скринам и получать данные. В консоли обычный вывод данных из приложения.
Подскажите как можно открыть скрин приложения и считать данные от туда? 
Я не требую готовых решений, нужно лишь направление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104426/display-content-of-all-currently-detached-screen